# Do I lose any photo quality with WiFi and AirDrop?

Tags: image-quality, storage

I am starting to develop more and more experience as an editorial photographer and I like to focus on current events around my city. That means that I find myself often submitting pics to Shutterstock from my car or other "mobile" locations to get my pictures approved as quickly as possible.

Right now I do:

1. Panasonic Lumix DMC-G7 saving to RAW+Fine
2. Connect my iPad to the G7 via the built in WiFi router; I can only download the JPEGs via this method, RAW cannot be done over WiFi
3. Panasonic ImageApp on my iPad to transfer the images and save them to my iPad camera roll
4. Use the iPad to review the images and decide which ones I actually want to submit
5. Send the images to my iPhone via AirDrop
6. Submit the images via the Shutterstock Contributor app

Does the above process introduce any loss of quality into my images? I have checked to make sure that the metadata is all there and it otherwise seems like the same image, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Are you a coder? Can you copy a sample JPEG from your memory card to a computer, and the "same" image from your iPhone to a computer. Do a bit-for-bit comparison. I'm sure some freeware is offered for your OS of choice for this. I'm not sure what the Shutterstock Contributor app does to files between upload and arriving on the Shutterstock website, but I would suppose it uploads full size original JPEGs.

Comment: @osullic You're right, I hadn't considered that I could do some hash/bitwise comparisons. I'll have to think about what that code looks like and cook something up.

Comment: why do you go the detour via iphone? even if your tablet doesn't have cell connectivity, it would seem easier to use the phone as a hotspot to send from the tablet.

Comment: @ths I do that because when I submit it's easier to write the captions on my iPhone than on my iPad. I know that's not a great reason, but I'm trying to write the most accurate captions I can.

Comment: @UnknownCoder What OS are you using? I use a program called Beyond Compare for all sorts of different operations. It's available for Windows, Mac and Linux, though it's not freeware (but is trialware). I'm not affiliated, other than as a very happy user, but I know that it is great at this kind of thing. It might be overkill if you just want to perform a one-off comparison of 2 images, but the point is, you don't need to write your own software to compare files.

Comment: Along the coding route, I'd like to recommend `Beyond Compare` which has an excellent photo compare viewer. I actually spotted differences AirDropping vs Image Capture importing of the same image. I'll author a post about this subject soon https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?viewpix.html

Answer (score 2):

1. There is normally no alteration of files in transport.
2. Image formats are compressed, random alterations wouldn't make the image slightly blurry but would create rather visible errors (assuming the image remains usable at all). For instance between these two images a single bit (bit, not even a byte) has changed:

[image]

[image]

3. The only unknown in this process is what Shutterstock does to their copy of your images.